# Move duplicates to the end of a sorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I was asked this question in an interview. 
There is a sorted array with duplicates. 
The goal is to return the array with unique elements first and duplicates at the end preserving the order. 
For example `[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]` should become `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4]`.

I was able to solve the question with an extra space (O(n) space) and linear time (O(n) time), but I am not sure if that is the best answer, ideally using no linear space.

I searched stackoverflow and found similar questions but not exactly the same. For example there was a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238023/sorting-an-array-while-moving-duplicates-to-the-end) sorting an array and moving duplicates to the end, but in my case the array is already sorted and the goal is to only move duplicates to the end.

Comment: can there be more than one duplicate for each number ? like say - [1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5] ? can this be a case, or max only two entries for a number can be present ?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @zenwraight we should just move duplicate elements to the end, and not discard any elements. In your example [1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1]

Comment: @apadana I think I understand your question now and updated my answer, can you kindly have a look at it  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your values are in limited range, there exists solution in O(n) time and O(1) space.

Determine the maximum value in array. Get some constant `C > arraymax`, as example - `C = 10` for your array.

Scan array, squeezing unique values and counting duplicates for every value. If value `V` has `K>0` duplicates, write `V+C*K` instead of value.

At the next scan find values with duplicates, extract number of duplicates and write them after squeezed unique values.

```
def dedup(lst):
    mx = max(lst) + 1
    dupcnt = 0
    delcnt = 0
    start = 0
    for i in range(1, len(lst) + 1):
        if i == len(lst) or (lst[i] != lst[start]):
            lst[start - delcnt] = lst[start] + dupcnt * mx
            delcnt += dupcnt
            start = i
            dupcnt = 0
        else:
            dupcnt += 1
    dupidx = len(lst) - delcnt
    for i in range(0, len(lst) - delcnt):
        dupcnt = lst[i] // mx
        if dupcnt:
           lst[i] %= mx
           for j in range(dupidx, dupidx+dupcnt):
              lst[j] = lst[i]
           dupidx += dupcnt
    return lst

print(dedup([1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5]))
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 4]
```

Comment: wouldn't traversing the array twice be n^2 ? That is why I didn't do it this way.

Comment: @Mike Q  No, double traversal requires `~2*N operations = O(N)`. Quadratic behavior is usual for algorithms with nested loops.

Comment: @MBo I will confess that I may be rusty in this area but I find it interesting that I can do it with one traversal of the list by just stacking them on the end of an expanding for loop and cleaning up afterwards... Wouldn't that be faster ?

Comment: @Mike Q  Your approach (as described) instantly reallocates array, causing slow work due to implicit (hidden in reallocation) quadratic complexity. You can remember deleted item, shift others and put deleted in the end cell - explicit quadratic run time. So this approach would be good for linked lists rather than arrays.

Comment: @MBo Well actually looking up the php function array_push it's basically doing about the same amount of work as your example, the advantage of yours is that it is a more clear example of what is going on .

Comment: @MBo I was thinking the same as you about quadratic complexity. But do you think this information contradicts that? From http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php : "Note: The unset() function allows removing keys from an array. Be aware that the array will not be reindexed." "An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack, queue, and probably more."

Comment: Additionally, this SO answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/5641288/2034787 , describes append as O(1) and unset as O(1). Source code: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c

Comment: @גלעד ברקן I knew that php "arrays" are not real arrays but without details. So php way is quite good - *for php*.

Comment: Yes, limited to PHP of course. Nice answer, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have 2-3 pointers (indexes):

- `i`: the next unique elements will be put at this position
- `j`: linear traversal pointer on the list

```c
private static void fix(int[] nums) {

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (j < nums.length) {

        int k;

        for (k = j + 1; (k < nums.length) && (nums[k] == nums[j]); k++) {}

        int tmp = nums[i];
        nums[i] = nums[j];
        nums[j] = tmp;

        j = k;
        i++;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of stating the obvious . . . an approach in *O*(*n* log *n*) time and *O*(1) extra space is:

1. Scan through the array to find the first element with each value, and swap that element directly into the correct position. (For example, when you reach the fourth distinct value, you swap the first element with that value into position #4.)

   - This step requires *O*(*n*) time and *O*(1) extra space.
   - After this step, the array consists of all unique elements in the correct order, followed by all the duplicates in garbage order.
2. Sort the duplicates using heapsort.

   - This step requires *O*(*n* log *n*) time and *O*(1) extra space.

Comment: Heapsort is not stable, so this will not preserve the order if the key is not the entire data.

Comment: @ruakh is there anything special about heapsort or it can be any sorting algorithm like quicksort?

Comment: @ruakh how does the swapping happen? swap unique element with sth from the end of the array? I didn't get exactly the swapping part.

Comment: @apadana: Re: "is there anything special about heapsort [...]?": Just that it's O(*n* log *n*) time and O(1) extra space. Quicksort, by contrast, is O(n²) time. (And despite n.m.'s comment about its not being stable, a stable sorting algorithm wouldn't actually help by this point, because the issue is that the elements have already been disordered.) Re: "how does the swapping happen?": You just keep track of the number of elements you've already swapped into place, so that you know the position to swap the next one into.

Comment: I like this answer. There is also a complement answer if the number of duplicates is significantly greater than unique values: keep a pointer to just before the start of the section of duplicates (this pointer starts at the end of the array) and keep swapping the element in that position with the duplicates as they are encountered while traversing the array backwards, then heapsort the section of unique values.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Misread your intentions where your concern was on space, this is the PHP version of "pointers". Since it's sorted we can just go through the loop once, right ? If not we would probably bake in duplicate sorting into the sort itself.

```
function findRepeating(&$arr)
{
    $size = count($arr);
    $previous = -99999;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        if ($i>0)
            $previous = $arr[$i-1];

        if ($arr[$i] == $previous) {
            array_push($arr,$arr[$i]); //push to end
            unset($arr[$i]); //then remove current one
        }
    }
    var_dump($arr);
}
```

We basically just take the current size of array and when we find duplicates push to the end of the array expanding it's size a little which is offset by the unset().

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [8]=>
  string(1) "4"
}
```

In a lower level language you could just shuffle around pointers because you know the end value so you take note of that and just append duplicates after that and add to the offset as it goes along. Totally achievable with or without arrays, with arrays we just swap around. My example is in PHP so instead of shuffling I just expand the array so I just use a single extra space temporarily .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Per php document, array_push() treats array as a stack, and pushes the passed variables onto the end of array . The length of array increases by the number of variables pushed. Because the array size changes it seems it's not a proper solution for interview.

Comment: PHP doesn't really allow for pointers so easily but either way you can see how this is a great minor compromise as it only adds one additional element at any given time which is immediately deleted  after it is "moved" .

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear one how multiple duplicates should be handled, or what you're asking precisely, **but I assume it's that you want to make sure that O(1) space is satisfied, regardless of time complexity,** so that's what I'll attempt to answer.

### With arrays, O(1) space, O(N^2) time:

You can do it in place by simply swapping the duplicate elements to the end. You can find duplicate elements by keeping a "current" pointer and simply checking that the "next" element isn't the same as the "current". **This is O(n^2) time in the worst case.** Example:

```
[1,1,2,3,4,4,5] # "cur" is index 0 (element 1), and "next" is index 1 (element 1). Swap "next" to end.
[1,2,1,3,4,4,5] # swapping
[1,2,3,1,4,4,5] # swapping
...             # Tedious swapping
[1,2,3,4,4,5,1] # Done swapping. Increment "cur".
[1,2,3,4,4,5,1] # "cur" is index 1 (element 2), and "next" is index 2 (element 3). Increment "cur"
...             # Boring (no duplicates detected)
[1,2,3,4,4,5,1] # "cur" is index 3 (element 4), and "next" is index 4 (element 4). Swap "next" to end.
[1,2,3,4,5,4,1] # swapping
[1,2,3,4,5,1,4] # Done swapping. Increment "cur"
...             # No more duplicates
# Done
```

As an aside, in practice trading time for less space typically isn't worth it. Memory is cheap, but slow response times can lose users, which is expensive. A notable exception is embedded systems where memory might be tight and inputs are short (on small inputs asymptotic runtime isn't relevant).

### With linked lists, O(1) space, O(N) time:

**If you had a linked list instead of an array, you could do this in O(n) time and O(1) space quite easily.** Linked lists have the advantage over arrays when you're forced to "shift" elements around since they can move pointers instead of moving ALL elements by a position. The cur/next strategy is similar for linked lists as above with the array. Here's an example:

```
1->1->2->3->4->4->5 # "cur" is first element (value 1), and "next" is second element (value 1). Swap "next" to the end.

1
 \
1->2->3->4->4->5    # Move "cur"'s pointer to "next"'s next element.

1->2->3->4->4->5->1 # Set "next"'s pointer to null, set tails pointer to "next"

...                 # Boring stuff with no duplicates

1->2->3->4->4->5->1 # "cur" is fourth element (value 4), and "next" is fifth element (value 4). Swap fifth element to end.

         4
          \
1->2->3->4->5->1    # Move "cur"'s pointer to "next"'s next element.

1->2->3->4->5->1->4 # Set "next"'s pointer to null, set tails pointer to "next"

...                 # No more duplicates
# Done (hopefully it's clear moving and element to the end is O(1) instead of O(n))
```

**If you could beat an array into a linked list in O(n) time and O(1) space, the problem is solved. However, this isn't possible.** Linked lists take up more space per element than an array does, so just by *having* a linked list anywhere in the program, I think O(1) space would be violated.

**Since it was an interview question though, it might have been worth pointing out that linked lists are a bit better for solving this problem efficiently, regardless of the problem statement. Typically interviewers like to see that you can apply data structures properly, and sometimes they're amenable to an input type change.**

> Smart data structures and dumb code works a lot better than the other
>   way around. --Eric S Raymond

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think we can still do better than O(n^2) by swapping the duplicates to the end of list, and sorting the unique part of the array (first part), which would be O(n log n).

Comment: Yes, good observation. I'll update later when I get a chance.

Comment: You can achieve with arrays, also you are sorting unnecessarily,  if you know that the last value '5' is the end, you just need to take note of that location/value and when you reach that stop or if current value is < previous. Also you just append the dup to the '5' value + offset or something.

Answer (score 0):

Here's C code that puts the duplicated strings at the last of the array.
The indicator array is used to indicates the index at which the string is duplicated.
ie: if s[0]==s[1] then indicator[1] will be assigned to 0 as at this index the string is repeated.
Then use indicator array to swap the duplicated string to last **valid** place in the array.

ie: if we found that indicator[1]=0 , this means that there is a duplicated string at index 1 and we need to move it to the last of the array, but what if the last element of the array is duplicated also!! then we should move forward to the second element from the end of the array

```
    void put_dublicates_to_last(char**s, int n)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, flag = 0,counter=0;
    int* indicator = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    char * temp;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        indicator[i] = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(s[i], s[j]) == 0)
            {
                //swap with the last element
                counter++;
                indicator[j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("counter is %d\n", counter);
    //use the indicator to swap with the last elements 
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = n; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            if (indicator[i] == 0)
            {
                if (indicator[j] != 0)
                {
                    //swap
                    temp = s[i];
                    s[i] = s[j-1];
                    s[j-1] = temp;
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }
            if (flag)
            {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }

        }

    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%s\n", s[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with single pointer and another pointer to find the next maximum if we don't care about the stability and the sortedness of the duplicate elements in the array.

Algorithm

- Start a pointer and iterate through the array as long as the element
  that you are at is greater than the previous and lesser than the next
- Once you see a break in this pattern, stop the increment and find a number that is greater than the current
- Swap this number with the next greater number.
- Continue this search till you can't find any more numbers that are greater in the array
- Break out of the loop if this condition is reached and return back the array

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
        int[] arr = {11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14,  15};
        rearrangeSort(arr);     
        for(int a : arr) {
            System.out.print(a + " ");
        }       
    }   
    public static void rearrangeSort(int[] arr){
        int unique = 1;
        int find = 0;
        while(unique < arr.length) {
            if(unique == 1 && (arr[unique - 1] == arr[unique])){
                find = findMax(arr, arr[unique], unique);
                swap(arr, unique, find);                
            }else if(unique == 1 && (arr[unique] == arr[unique + 1])){
                find = findMax(arr, arr[unique], unique);
                swap(arr, unique + 1, find);                
            }           
            if(unique > 0 && (arr[unique - 1] < arr[unique]) && (arr[unique] < arr[unique + 1])){
                unique++;
            }
            find = findMax(arr, arr[unique], unique);           
            if(find == 0) {break;}
            swap(arr, unique+1, find);
        }                   
    }       
    public static int findMax(int[] arr, int target, int index){
        while(index < arr.length) {
            if(arr[index] > target) {return index;}
            index++;
        }
        return 0;
    }       
    public static void swap(int[] arr, int idx1, int idx2){
        int temp = arr[idx1];
        arr[idx1] = arr[idx2];
        arr[idx2] = temp;       
    }
}
```