# Sort DataFrame, moving duplicates to the end

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a list containing number `[1,1,2,2,3,3]`. How can I sort this list to `[1,2,3,1,2,3]`?

Let me elaborate what it used for. I have a pandas dataframe

```
columnA columnB columnC
A       a        1       
A       a        1
A       b        2
A       b        2
B       a        1
B       a        1
B       b        2
B       b        2
```

I would like to have it reordered like:

```
columnA columnB columnC
A       a        1       
A       b        2
A       a        1
A       b        2
B       a        1
B       b        2
B       a        1
B       b        2
```

I have tried sort_values function, but it seems not works.

Comment: `list(set([1,1,2,2,3,3]))*2`

Comment: Looks like you have already done it. If you want to do other cases as well, you should tell us about them. And show your efforts.

Comment: What would be the output if the list was `[1,1,1,2,2,3]`?

Comment: I think this could be done with a combination of `sort` + `GroupBy` + iterating through successive elements of the groups to move them to the end of the dataframe.

Comment: Related question: [Move duplicates to the end of a sorted array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52123949/move-duplicates-to-the-end-of-a-sorted-array/52503076)

Comment: @Stef Thanks for bring this up. the case ```[1,1,1,2,2,3]``` won't be appear in my scenario, the data length in columnC is fixed, they always come with an equal sequence.

Comment: I found a workaround by adding one more column which is specific to my data. It is not a generic solution. However, I believe it is still a valid problem need to be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to count duplicate values and use this count as a key to move duplicates to the end:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('dataduplicates.csv')
df['duplicate_key'] = df.groupby('columnC').cumcount()
df.sort_values(['duplicate_key', 'columnC'], inplace=True)

print(df)
#   columnA columnB  columnC  duplicate_key
# 0       A       a        1              0
# 2       A       b        2              0
# 1       A       a        1              1
# 3       A       b        2              1
# 4       B       a        1              2
# 6       B       b        2              2
# 5       B       a        1              3
# 7       B       b        2              3
```

Comment: It is truly a general solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can do sth tricky like:

```py
nums = [1,1,2,2,3,3]
nums_set = set(nums)

sorted_nums = list(nums_set) * (len(nums)/len(nums_set))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The solution is similar to what @j__carlson provided. For sure it works if it is a solely list order problem, but it does not work for the data frame issue described below.